# .htaccess Redirect 301 adding text to URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Redirect information within the .htaccess file, Example ...

```
Redirect 301 /armaflex.html http://www.just-insulation.com/002-brands/armaflex.html
```

Returns this response in the URL bar of ... 
    http://www.just-insulation.com/002-brands/armaflex.html?file=armaflex
I am at a loss to understand why the additional text "?file=armaflex" is added

The following code is inserted at the top of the file ...

```
RewriteEngine On
# redirect html pages to the root domain
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
# Force www. prefix in URLs and redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^just-insulation.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.just-insulation.com/ [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Which domain is your `Redirect 301` rule on? On the `just-insulation.com` domain are there more than one htaccess file?

Comment: The Redirect 301 rule is in the root directory of just-insulation.com. there more than one htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry, there is only one .htaccess file.